# issues with print, format, println - java

Tags: java

I started learning java with the *deitel* book and I'm doing the exercises they wrote.
Suddenly after changing my java dir path (when opening) i started encountering problems with the printing methods like *printf*, *format*, *println* the compiler shows me that there is an error with it but it worked before and i changed back the path...opening a new class and still same problem, any thoughts?

also, does anyone have a link to a file or a webpage with multiple exercises in java with solutions?

```
package examples;


 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class exampleOne {
public static int j=0;
public static void main (String [] args){
    boolean [] seats = new boolean [10];
    for(int i=0; i< seats.length; i++)
        seats[i]=false;

Scanner clasScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char c=' ';
while (c != '1' || c !='2' ){
System.out.println("Please choose the class of your choice:\n Press 1 for First class\n Press 2 for Economy\n");
String choice = clasScanner.next();
c = choice.charAt(0);
if(c == '1')
    {
        System.out.print("you choce First class\n");
        while (seats[j]==true && j<5)
                j++;
        seats[j]=true;
        System.out.printf("your seat is numbered %d", j+1);

        break;
    }
if(c == '2')
    {
        System.out.print("you choce Eonomy class\n");
        break;
    }

}
}

}
```

even this wont work:

```
public class Test {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int i=6;
    System.out.printf("this is i: %d", i);
}
}
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)
    The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int)    
    at examples.Date.<init>(Date.java:17)
    at examples.EmployeeTest.main(EmployeeTest.java:6)"
```

tnx a lot

Comment: Tell us what kind of error are you getting so we can help better

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)
 The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int)

 at examples.Date.<init>(Date.java:17)
 at examples.EmployeeTest.main(EmployeeTest.java:6)

Comment: Post complete code, including main().

Comment: looks like you have some issue with configuration, there is no problem  with your code. Two questions: 1- What exactly do you mean by " Suddenly after changing my java dir path"? 2- Did you not have this issue before doing the changes?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using IDE such as Eclipse that I would recommend check project build path and also check for compile errors that should be highlighted by IDE.

If you are not using IDE recompile whole project to check if there are compile errors.
From research I have done I found that in the most of cases this error is thrown when different type of compilers are used (IDE might use slightly different one) or that you are trying to run code that has compile errors (some IDE allows you to run such a code).

To make sure problems are not caused by buggy code but environment best what you can do is to create complete new project and copy your code there and run code from new project

EDIT: my first answer was incorrect

Comment: its weird because one example worked before and the other is from the book so it most work :)

Comment: Posting links to other answers does not constitute an answer in itself.